# A question from Analysis: Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have not been able to solve this specific question pertaining to differentiation for the course real analysis. How would you go about on this one?

> Show that if $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ and $g^{(n)}(x_0)$ exist and
>   $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0,$$
>   then $f^{(r)}(x_0)=g^{(r)}(x_0)$ for all $0\le r\le n$.

A step-by-step solution would be great. Thank you.

Update: So here's what I have tried so far!

Applied taylor

$ 
[f(x) - g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (f^k(xo) - g^k(xo))(x-xo)^k]
$

$
\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{(x-xo)^n} = \frac{1}{(x-xo)^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (f^k(xo) - g^k(xo))(x-xo)^k
$

$
\lim \frac{f(x) - g(x)}{(x-xo)^n} = \lim \frac{1}{(x-xo)^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (f^k(xo) - g^k(xo))(x-xo)^k
$

$
\lim \frac{f(x) - g(x)}{(x-xo)^n} = \lim \frac{1}{(x-xo)^n} ((f(x) - g(x))+(f^n(x) - g^n(x))=0
$

and hence,

$
(f^n(xo) - g^n(xo))=0
$

Is it correct?

Comment: Would L'Hopital be a solution ?

Comment: ps please change title to something more descriptive , and replace image by $ LaTeX$

Comment: I apologize, I am new on this website and I was unsure as to what title would suit my question

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I know you're new, so maybe you're not aware that your question looks like you just a took a screengrab of one your homework problems and are looking for someone to do it for you.  Dispel that notion by explaining which parts of the problem you *do* understand.

Answer (score 3):

Set $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Then you have
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{h(x)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0
$$
and you want to prove $h^{(k)}=0$ for $0\le k\le n$. Since the function $h$ is differentiable $n$ times at $x_0$, you can consider the Taylor expansion
$$
h(x)=h(x_0)+\frac{h^{(1)}(x_0)}{1!}(x-x_0)+\frac{h^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2
+\dots+
\frac{h^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^{n}+\varphi(x)(x-x_0)^n
$$
where $\lim_{x\to x_0}\varphi(x)=0$.

For simplicity, set $c_k=h^{(k)}(x_0)/k!$, so we can write
$$
\frac{h(x)-h(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=
\frac{c_1(x-x_0)^{n-1}+c_2(x-x_0)^{n-2}+\dots+c_{n-1}(x-x_0)+c_n}{(x-x_0)^n}+\varphi(x)
$$
Since this limit is $0$ by hypothesis, you get $c_n=0$. Therefore
$$
\frac{h(x)-h(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=
\frac{c_1(x-x_0)^{n-2}+c_2(x-x_0)^{n-3}+\dots+c_{n-1}}{(x-x_0)^{n-1}}+\varphi(x)
$$
and again $c_{n-1}=0$. Go on.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Using Taylor's expansion of $f,g$ at $x_0$, and then L'hospitale rule:$\dfrac{f(x) - g(x)}{(x-x_0)^n} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(f^{k}(x_0) - g^{k}(x_0))(x-x_0)^k}{(x-x_0)^n}$